# Chartjs - improve performance for line charts with many (hundreds) datasets

Tags: javascript, performance, chart.js, react-chartjs, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I am using `chart.js` and `chartjs-plugin-zoom` to produce a real-time zoomable, pannable line graph containing around 200-400 datasets, each with anywhere from 10-50 data points. Needless to say, the chart contains thousands of points in total and performance suffers.

Currently, rendering the chart takes a few seconds depending on the amount of data, and zooming/panning the graph is extremely choppy. I have noticed that the sheer number of datasets hurts performance even more than the sheer number of points, and I am wondering how to improve performance to make the experience faster and smoother.

I have seen the chart.js doc page on performance [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/performance.html), but I cannot disable point/line drawing, and I cannot use data decimation because I need to see every point.

A few questions:

1. Are there any other optimizations for large numbers of datasets?
2. Are there any optimizations/improvements for `chartjs-plugin-zoom`?
3. Failing any available improvements with chart.js, are there any other open-source libraries that could handle this type of work (and include zoom functionality)?